# How does Drupal's security compare to Plone's?

Tags: drupal, plone

How does Drupal's security compare to Plone's?

### Note:

It will be great if the comparison includes V.7 for Drupal and V.4 for Plone.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security of the main framework is pretty solid in both cases; the problems are almost always found in the add-on modules, so you need to evaluate each module you plan to use individually.

Answer (score 14):

There's a good overview of how Plone handles the top 10 security issues in the web app world here:

http://plone.org/products/plone/security/overview

Organizations like the FBI, CIA and European Network and Information Security Agency (ENISA) all use Plone, if that is an indication.

Plone has the best track record in security of any major CMS, and we take it very seriously. We have an architecture that is built around sandboxing, proper ACLs and a powerful security model.

Drupal has a pretty horrible security record (see the CVE numbers quoted in another comment), as do the other two major PHP-based frameworks (Wordpress and Joomla). Plone is Python-based, but you probably know that already.

Plone makes it easier to write secure add-ons, since we have a proper security model that makes it pretty hard to write code that is inherently insecure. This is different from any other system out there, and is another core differentiator.

(And yes, this answer is biased, I'm one of the founders ;)

Comment: The choice of language has *nothing* to do with security.

Comment: The choice of language has a lot to do with security.  With C, you have to do your own memory management. So you have buffer overflows and so on, which are the basis for most viruses.  With dynamic languages (python, ruby, perl, php), this is not a problem.  So: language choice matters.  Regarding PHP versus Python: python was made for clean and neat programming, php for adding simple automation to "parsed html pages".  Different set of safeguards needed. PHP, imho, exists to allow you to do everything. So python seems more secure to me.

Comment: @limi please look at this drupal user https://drupal.org/user/2356044 (whitehouse.gov) when you talk about security.

Answer (score 3):

When searching the "CVE" official common vulnerabilities database, you get the following figures:

Last 3 years: plone 8, drupal 282.

Last 3 months: plone 0, drupal 9

The basic architecture of plone is apparently much more secure.  I don't know drupal, actually, but I do know plone.  There are no sql injection bugs as there's an non-sql object database behind it.  It is a long-running python program, basically, instead of PHP scripts, which makes it easier to have a good solid security mechanism that's harder to break or mis-handle.

(Note: I just did a simple keyword search at http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search .  Not all the results I see for drupal can be attributed to drupal, there seem to be some os-level vulnerabilities that somehow show up in the search results).

Comment: In the defense of Drupal, of the 9 recent entries in that list, most are listed as affecting old versions and most are in non-core modules. The only one of high severity is in an obscure weather forecast module. My point about checking your modules is important. I wonder whether the discrepancy in those figures you listed is down to the quantity (and quality) of third-party modules available for each platform?

Comment: The "quantity" argument is a bit the same as windows versus OSX regarding viruses.  Does OSX have less viruses because it is darn well impossible to write a decent virus for a security-consious unix-based OS?  Or does it have less viruses because windows is used more often?

Comment: Regarding non-core modules: it is apparently easy/customary to write non-core modules that have major security breaches.

Comment: Re the quantity argument: I'd say it's a bit of both: MacOS is better secured.. but if it were as popular as Windows you can be quite sure it'd have a lot more viruses. Re your point about it being easy to write bad modules: Agreed, and that's where the major problem lies. Its typical of a lot of things with a low barrier to entry: its easy for novices to produce results that look good, but unless they understand what's going on under the hood they will produce security problems. So you really need to know about quality of the modules you pick.

Comment: See http://drupalsecurityreport.org/sites/drupalsecurityreport.org/files/drupal-security-white-paper-1-1.pdf for an out-of-date (mid 2010) comparison of drupal core vs contrib security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to compare Plone and Drupal on equal metrics. CVEs is not the end-all comparison, and it's arguable how valuable it even is, as an indication of the relative security of the software. Of those 282 Drupal CVEs, how many were for Drupal core? Not 282.

limi can argue that the architecture is more secure, and point to Plone's response to the OWASP Top Ten. Drupal can do the same. And the "who uses it" argument? Well, whitehouse.gov uses Drupal, as well as a large number of other governmental and "enterprise" organizations.

Answer (score 0):

There are several orders of magnitude more developers using Drupal; the higher numbers of vulnerabilities found can just as easily be attributed to more people bothering to look for them.  These stats could easily be security by obscurity.